# Log in to StackOverflow without Google or Facebook

Tags: support

I have signed up for SO using my google account and have also used Facebook to sign in too. 
But due to some change in policies my company has decided to block Google accounts(only search is available) and Facebook. 
How can I log into my same SO account without Google Sign In?
Can I use OpenID and how?

Comment: I think you send an email them regarding your account details.  So they can help you in merging you account to your new domain(whatever it is).

Comment: If you have internet access elsewhere, you can change your OpenID provider to Stack Exchange's own service.

Comment: how can i do it?